# Best way to input and store date in bootstrap/laravel?

Tags: html, laravel, date, input, twitter-bootstrap-3

please tell me best way to generate input date in bootstrap template and then store it in laravel db.

Also how to make form input with mask as dd/mm/yyyy with minimum code and js addons?

Answer (score 0):

You can use moment.js to parse your date and place it in your field for date.

`moment('your date value here').format('dd/mm/yyyy');`

```js
$(function(){
  $("#sample").val(moment('2017-04-23').format('DD/MM/YYYY'));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="sample" value=""/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can parse any date format using `parse()` and `createFromFormat()` [Carbon methods](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) before saving it to DB:

```
$createdAt = Carbon::parse($request->date);
```

You can also transform the date to any format:

```
$createdAt = $model->created_at->format('Y-m-d');
```

You can do this automatically with [accessors and mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators).